# Are there any applications of linear algebra over the complex numbers, where the role of complex conjugation is replaced with the trivial involution?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups

The complex inner product $\langle u, v \rangle$ is a special case of a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form#Over_arbitrary_rings) over a field. Its definition is $\langle u, v \rangle = \sum_{i} u_i \overline{v_i}$. There is clearly the possibility of changing this to another sesquilinear form (which happens to also be a bilinear form, unlike the former example) $(u,v) = \sum_{i} u_i v_i$. My question concerns the bilinear form $(u,v)$. Intriguingly, the two sesquilinear forms have comparable properties, including analogous matrix decompositions with respect to each of them -- for instance, the Algebraic Polar Decomposition versus the usual Polar Decomposition.

While there may be results about linear algebra with respect to the above bilinear form, I'm not sure if there are any *applications*. What applications, if any, are known?

Aside: It might be notable that if the complex numbers were changed to the dual numbers (which are sadly not a field) then there might be a reason to consider matrix algebra with respect to them, where the preferred analogue of the "inner product" is $(u,v) = \sum_{i} u_i v_i$ rather than $\langle u, v \rangle = \sum_{i} u_i \overline{v_i}$. There appear to be connections to *screw theory*, which is an important approach to the physics of rigid bodies.

Comment: Quadratic forms and their orthogonal groups are widely studied over arbitrary fields, and the complex case is an essential one. Of course this goes beyond linear algebra. At the level of differential geometry, I'm not sure what the name of the corresponding objects (complex manifold endowed with non-degenerate quadratic form on the tangent space at every point) is.

Comment: For the classification of simple Lie algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ one uses the Killing form, which is a bilinear form.

Answer (score 1):

[On the generalization of the Wigner semicircle law to real symmetric tensors](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02660) studies the complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a real symmetric tensor $T\in\otimes^p\mathbb{R}^N$, subject to the eigenvector normalization $x^2=1$, not $x\bar{x}=1$.
As discussed in [The number of eigenvalues of a tensor](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4953), the normalization without complex conjugation ensures that there are at most $[(p − 1)N − 1]/(p − 2)$ eigenvalues, with complex conjugation there would be a continuous infinity of eigenvalues.